# removing excess tab from loop in perl

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop

a basic question involving loops. If I'm doing a basic loop where I want to generate a tab delimited table from a hash of hashes (format: $hash_of_table_data{$headers}{$entry} = 1) with example code:

```
foreach my $rowheader (keys %hash_of_table_data) {
  print "$rowheader\t";
  foreach my $entry (keys %{ $hash_of_table_data{$rowheader}}) {
    print "$entry\t";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

So, by doing loops like this, at the end of print my last element of each row, it will have an extra tab. Is there a simple way to generate a similar list but that wouldn't add the extra tab at the very end? Or some simple chomp like function that will remove the last tab added prior to doing the new line? (I want it to add tabs between every element, except the final element).

Comment: Use the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have commented, `join` seems to be a nice solution for this problem.
You can do this in a single line:

```
print join("\t", $_, keys %{$hash{$_}}) . "\n" foreach keys %hash;
```